# Google App Engine Email Very Slow Delivery

Tags: email, google-app-engine

I'm a long time paid user of Google App Engine.

More recently I've noticed that Google has changed their quotas for sending email and reduced the service very significantly:

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas#Mail

Now the problem I've currently got is that any emails I send via the python interface are being delivered sometimes more than 12 hours later.

This hasn't happened in the past. We use these emails to alert our users to certain data states and need the emails to be delivered quickly.

Is there anything I can do to speed this up? Can I add additional headers, specify priorities, change DNS or anything else?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance,
Matt

Answer (score 0):

The best option for me was to use a service such as SendGrid. 
It's a real email service provider, you can even authenticate your domain (DKIM, DMARC..).

It has a great free quota and for experience, is kinda fast!